# Using Java for base conversions - help I think the summing of decimals or conversion part is off

Tags: java, data-conversion

I'm analyzing the contents of a data file with entries in the form: ABCDE, followed by the base BB. The goals are to process the file, convert each to decimal (base 10) and determine the sum of the decimal (base 10) values.

Reject any entry that is invalid, thus far I found 5 entries that are invalid.

But I think I am not either converting each to decimal base 10 correctly or summing these decimals properly. Currently my sum is: -587582260 which is incorrect!

Here is the full program:

```
//Class for converting a number with a base value to decimal from each line in a file
public class anyBaseToDecimal {
    // Main function
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Declares line as string to store a line in file
        String lines, numString;
        // Declares 4 integer variables
        int base, power, total = 0, val, decimal;
        // Declare a character variable letter to store each character in numString
        char letter;
        // Opens a file in read mode
        FileReader file = new FileReader("BaseConversionInput.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);
        // Gets each line till end of file is reached
        while ((lines = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // Splits each line into words using method split()
            String wordsArray[] = lines.split(" ");
            // Sets numString as first word in wordsArray
            numString = wordsArray[0];
            // Convert numString to uppercase
            numString = numString.toUpperCase();
            // Convert second word in array to integer and store it as base value
            base = Integer.parseInt(wordsArray[1]);
            // set decimal as 0 . It is used for storing decimal equivalent of number
            decimal = 0;
            // set power as 1
            power = 1;
            // Repeat the loop through each character in numString
            for (int i = numString.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                // Set letter as ith character of numString
                letter = numString.charAt(i);
                // If letter is a digit set value as letter-48. It is equivalent to its integer
                // value
                if (letter >= '0' && letter <= '9') {
                    val = letter - 48;
                } else {
                    // Set val as decimal equivalent of character ie A=10,B=11,C=12 etc
                    val = letter - 'A' + 10;
                }
                // If val is greater than or equal to base print invalid number and goto next
                // line
                if (val >= base) {
                    System.out.println("Not a valid number!");
                    break;
                }
                decimal += power * val;
                power = power * base;
                total += decimal;
            }
            // Display decimal equivalent of number
            System.out.println(decimal);
        }
        // display total
        System.out.println("total of decimal equivalent of numbers present in given file: " + total);
        // closes the file
        br.close();
    }
}
```

Contents of the data file consists of entries such as this:

k5Jjc0mAd 23

182152334a 13

42122320204 5

52310 7

99CG 18

2 19

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: If the sum is very large you might get an integer overflow. If the number stored in an int is larget than rougly 2.1 billion it will overflow and give a negative number. Try long instead of int if this is the case. Then you can store up to something like 9 billion billions :D

Comment: Code quality-wise you have a lot of meaningless comments that just state the same as the code does. Also, try to avoid reusing variables when you don't have to, as it might lead to strange errors, since you don't start fresh with each iteration.

Comment: As noted in an answer, you need to move the addition to total outside the loop. Also, you could check for overflow. You can't quite do `if (total + decimal > Integer.MAX_VALUE)` because `total + decimal` would overflow, the exact thing you're trying to guard against, but you can rearrange it algebraically, subtracting `decimal` from both sides, and do `if (total > Integer.MAX_VALUE - decimal)`, then report an error, throw an `ArithmeticException`, etc. Just in case, better safe than sorry.

Comment: Note: You can also use [`Math.addExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#addExact(int,int)).

Answer (score 1):

You are summing incorrectly.

The line:

```
total += decimal;
```

Should be outside the `for` loop, otherwise you will keep adding partial sums, getting much bigger sum value than you should.

The reason you are getting a negative sum, is because your sum "rolls over" (goes above maximum integer size).

You should use `long` for `total` or perhaps even `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Okay just updated the code, instead of using int, I used long for total: long total = 0;  Then I moved `total += decimal; ` to outside of the for loop! The decimal equivalent changed quite a bit! If I wanted to try using BigDecimal for total, what would the syntax for that look like? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No need to use BigDecimal since the values are all integers, but you may want to use BigInteger.